# writing the output of a for loop to a new file

Tags: python-2.7

i have a file called pfile which has a table that looks like this but in 750 lines:

```
1402082731.612315
#   1   M     0.999     0.002
    2   A     0.999     0.001
    3   E     1.000     0.001
    4   P     0.998     0.003
    5   R     0.997     0.003
    6   Q     0.994     0.009
```

and i need to write all the third row which is [2] to a new file called Quantum score.txt.
i wrote

```
A = open('Pfile.pondrfit', 'r')
header1 = A.readline()
header2 = A.readline()
header3 = A.readline()
for line in A:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    score = str(columns[2])
    print score
```

FYI this prints all the quantum scores of the columns exactly as i want it so i decided to write that to a new file and yes i indented

```
x = open("quantum.txt", "w")
x.write(score)
x.close()
```

however ONLY the column 2 of the last line which in this case is 0.994  prints to that file>

how do i make sure all the 750 columns print to it

Comment: Take out the [2] would be my guess.

Comment: if i remove the [2] the whole column prints. that first section works just fine but i need all that 750 lines copied to a file

Comment: Where did you put `x = open("quantum.txt", "w")`?

Comment: after the print exactly where it shows on  the screen